# How to remove $ for json result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to read a cell value from a simple google sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1opP1t_E9xfuLXBkhuyzo5j9k_xBNDx0XKb31JwLP1MM/edit?usp=sharing

then I published it and I get an **API** link that return **JSON**, check the following 
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1opP1t_E9xfuLXBkhuyzo5j9k_xBNDx0XKb31JwLP1MM/1/public/values?alt=json

when I tried to generate **C#** classes from **JSON** using http://json2csharp.com/, I get

> invalid_name and $ (which is not fine for csharp compiler)

```
public class Id
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Updated
{
    public DateTime __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string scheme { get; set; }
    public string term { get; set; }
}

public class Title
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Email email { get; set; }
}

public class OpenSearchTotalResults
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class OpenSearchStartIndex
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Id2
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Updated2
{
    public DateTime __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Category2
{
    public string scheme { get; set; }
    public string term { get; set; }
}

public class Title2
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Link2
{
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class GsxName
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class GsxPhonenumber
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public Id2 id { get; set; }
    public Updated2 updated { get; set; }
    public List<Category2> category { get; set; }
    public Title2 title { get; set; }
    public Content content { get; set; }
    public List<Link2> link { get; set; }
    public GsxName __invalid_name__gsx$name { get; set; }
    public GsxPhonenumber __invalid_name__gsx$phonenumber { get; set; }
}

public class Feed
{
    public string xmlns { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__xmlns$openSearch { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__xmlns$gsx { get; set; }
    public Id id { get; set; }
    public Updated updated { get; set; }
    public List<Category> category { get; set; }
    public Title title { get; set; }
    public List<Link> link { get; set; }
    public List<Author> author { get; set; }
    public OpenSearchTotalResults __invalid_name__openSearch$totalResults { get; set; }
    public OpenSearchStartIndex __invalid_name__openSearch$startIndex { get; set; }
    public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string encoding { get; set; }
    public Feed feed { get; set; }
}
```

I want to serialize and deserialize this class, also i want to remove $,what i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously json2csharp converts each json object into a class and converts the key names into variable names literally. So whenever it finds a key name starting with $ it can't create a c# variable with this character and it precedes the variable name with a _invalid_name_. There is nothing wrong here.

You should tell why do you want to remove this invalid_name phrase from variable name? do you want to serialize and deserialize this class? If so you could use NewtonSoft Json library and define those fields with $ sign like this:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$t")]
public string t { get; set; }
```

this will allow you to serialize/deserialize the json doc

same for gsx$name:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "gsx$name")]
public string gsxname { get; set; }
```

Comment: it is working fine, i removed $ and used JsonProperty. nice answer thanks